# Return a string with the first letter, then the letter one index from the first, then the letter 2 indices from the second, etc?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to create a function that accepts a string of any length and then a string with the first letter, then the letter one index from the first, then the letter 2 indices from the second, etc. Say I have a string:

```
my_string = "0123456789"
```

Expected output:

```
'0136'
```

or another example

```
my_string = "0123456789ABCDEFG"
```

Expected output:

```
'0136AF'
```

Things I have tried:

```
#Try 1
new_string = ""
for i in range(len(string)):
    new_string += string[:i+i]
print(new_string)


#Try 2
new_string = ""
for i in range(len(string)):
    new_string += string[:(i*(i+1))/2]
print(new_string)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have made an empty string, and then tried using a for loop, by indices, and slicing the string inside that for loop and adding that string to the new one. I tried something like string[:i+i], but that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Try to come up with a formula that generates the indices you need: 0, 1, 3, 6, 10... Or, if you're lazy, plug the numbers into https://oeis.org/ and copy the formula of whatever sequence turns up :-)

Comment: Can you edit your question and post any (relevant) code you have?

Comment: From the question it is not even entirely clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following simple while-loop, maintaining index and increment:

```
string = "0123456789ABCDEFG"
new_string, ind, inc = "", 0, 0
while ind < len(string):
    new_string += string[ind]
    inc += 1
    ind += inc
new_string
# '0136AF'
```

Or use fancy `itertools`:

```
from itertools import accumulate, count, takewhile

string = "0123456789ABCDEFG"
''.join(string[i] for i in takewhile(lambda x: x < len(string), accumulate(count())))
# '0136AF'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the triangle numbers (thanks @kevin) and then grab the indices, returning if we get an `IndexError` (we've reached the end of the string)

```
def triangles():
    # could be improved with itertools.count
    count = 1
    index = 0
    while True:
        yield index
        index += count
        count += 1

def get_tri_indices(s):
    res = []
    for index in triangles():
        try:
            res.append(s[index])
        except IndexError:  # we're out of range
            return ''.join(res)
```

output

```
get_tri_indices('0123456789abcdef')  # --> 0136af
```

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, here's the definitive `itertools`-abuse answer.

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate, count, takewhile
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> 
>>> def accuchars(s):
...     idx = takewhile(lambda x: x < len(s), accumulate(count()))
...     return ''.join(itemgetter(*idx)(s))
... 
>>> my_string = "0123456789ABCDEFG"
>>> accuchars(my_string)
'0136AF'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use accumulate [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and add operator

```
from toolz import accumulate
from operator import add
my_string = "0123456789ABCDEFG"
''.join([my_string[i] for i in accumulate(add,range(len(my_string))) if i <len(my_string)])
```

Output

```
'0136AF'
```

Comment: `toolz`? Is that a wrapper for `itertools`?

Comment: It is an extension of `itertools`

Answer (score 0):

The number sequence you want to generate is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), where each `n+1` is the sum of `0..n`. To get the list of numbers, you can iterate and add them up but it is also possible to generate it using a list comprehension. The formula `n(n+1)/2` gives the *n*th triangular number, so

```
[n*(n+1)//2 for n in range(20)]
>>> [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91, 105, 120, 136, 153, 171, 190]
```

But before you can use this, you need to know the *final* number for your string length. You cannot plug in any sufficiently large number for the `range` as Python will otherwise complain

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

So you need the [reverse of the formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778490/reversing-the-tn-fracnn12-formula); this will give you the value *m* where *Tri*(*m*) ≤ `len(string)`:

```
[x*(x+1)//2 for x in range(int(((1+8*len(my_string))**0.5)/2+.999))]
>>> [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Now you have a reliable method to generate just the indexes you need, so you can grab the characters

```
[my_string[x*(x+1)//2] for x in range(int(((1+8*len(my_string))**0.5)/2+.999))]
>>> ['0', '1', '3', '6', 'A', 'F']
```

... and join them together in a single list comprehension:

```
print (''.join(my_string[x*(x+1)//2] for x in range(int(((1+8*len(my_string))**0.5)/2+.999))))
>>> 0136AF
```